# Angular: Change the spelling of 1 word throughout an application for internationalization

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, internationalization

I have an angular application that needs to read in both British and American English.
The language setting/code comes from a server at start-up so I know which language to display.

Throughout the app I need to change the word 'colour' to 'color'. This is the only change I need to make, but it's in a lot of places, including the routing so the URL will be effected.

What is the best way to achieve this, preferably at a global level without going into each template and adding a i18n attribute to each tag (unless that is in fact what I need to do).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need to write a language setting for each language. Thats the common way and the only one, I think. I know it can be much work. But each language can have special things.
If you only want to change some words in a dirty way - thats my mind - you can create a pipe like this as example:

##### Create pipe

`ng g p replace-pipe`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'replace'
})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, regexValue: string, replaceValue: string): any {
    let regex = new RegExp(regexValue, 'g');
    return value.replace(regex, replaceValue);
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
TYPESCRIPT
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  stringText = 'Thats my colour';
}


HTML
<p> {{stringText | replace:'colour':'color'}}</p>
```

The words **"color" and "colour"** can come from a backend and can be dynamically.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this over say, creating a i18n attribute and a config file that does the same thing?

Comment: You can handle it how you want. The i18n way is the cleaner way. I would you show an alternative if you need to change only one word (color -> colour) as example.